# When handle all promises and other stuff, Get request not returning data, still sending

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, nestjs

I am trying to query some data in my data. But when I send get request to my server, It's not returning anything. But when I console log my data is printed on the console. I handle all promises and other stuff. But the results are the same.

Controller method: -

```
  @Get('order/:state')
  async getOrderByStatus(
    @Res() response: Response,
    @Param('state') state: number,
  ): Promise<OrderService[]> {
    try {
      const orderStatus = await this.orderServiceService.getOrderByStatus(
        state,
      );
      if (orderStatus) {
        console.log(orderStatus);
        return orderStatus;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      response.status(401).send(error);
    }
  }
```

Service method: -

```
  async getOrderByStatus(state: number): Promise<OrderService[]> {
    try {
      const orderState = await this.orderModel.find({ orderStatus: state });
      if (orderState) {
        return orderState;
      }
      throw new HttpException('Order not found', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Client-side:- (Request data is still sending.Not returning data from my controller)
[image]

I really need your help... Thank you..❤️

Comment: How (with which code) did you conclude that "it's not returning anything"?

Comment: @trincot  request data is not returning to my client side from controller methord.

Comment: Please add the code to your question which is capturing the data at the client side.

Comment: Shouldn't you have  a `send` somewhere? I don't know nestjs, but I would expect a `response.send` call to return the response to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `@Res()` to the route handler, you are telling Nest that you want to use the [library-specific approach](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#library-specific-approach) and you'll handle sending the response on your own. If you don't need any underlying engine specific methods, I'd suggest not using `@Res()` in the route handler, and if you do need some method, but still want Nest to send the response you can end up using `@Res({ passthrough: true })`, just make sure that you don't end up calling `res.send` yourself.

For handling the error, you can catch the error and re-throw it as an `HttpException`, that way Nest's built-in exception filter will send the proper response code and message for you